# Django - How to make multiple objects dynamic in the same page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Problem statement: Unable to make multiple elements dynamic in the same index page. Can you suggest me how to do it? I have almost 5 elements to be made dynamic in the same page.
I am using the following code

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_a, name='index'),
    path('', views.index_b, name = 'lunch')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import breakfast, lunch

# Create your views here.
def index_a(request):
    brkfstn = breakfast.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html",{'brkfstn':brkfstn})

def index_b(request):
    lunchn = lunch.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html",{'lunchn':lunchn})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class breakfast(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingrdnt = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    offer_price = models.IntegerField()

class lunch(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingrdnt = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    discount = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    offer_price = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: @ Libin Thomas  If you don't have problem with the usage of ```Ajax``` I can help you with it, and recommend using ```Ajax``` in this scenario.

Comment: I just started learning. Would like to stick to the basics for now. Thanks for asking though.@iliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my mistake.
Can add more elements in the dictionary in views.py

So updated my views.py as below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import breakfast, lunch

# Create your views here.
def index_a(request):
    brkfstn = breakfast.objects.all()
    lunchn = lunch.objects.all()
    return render(request, "index.html",{'brkfstn':brkfstn, 'lunchn':lunchn'})
```